# Using call_user_func with method_exists

Tags: php

Try to call method_exists on method registred with call_user_func.

```
<?php 

class stdClass1
{
    public static $methods = [];

    public function __call($method, $arguments) {
        return call_user_func_array(Closure::bind(self::$methods[$method], $this, get_called_class()), $arguments);
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        if (is_callable($value)) {
            self::$methods[$name] = $value;
        } else {
            parent::__set($name, $value);
        }
    }

}

class stdClass2
{
    function stdRunMethod()
    {
        $obj = new stdClass1();
        $obj->test = function () {
            echo 'a simple function'.PHP_EOL;
        };
        var_dump(method_exists($obj, "test"));
    }
}
$obj = new stdClass2();
$obj->stdRunMethod();
```

method_exists return false. How to check this method with method_exists? Why method_exists return false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `test` is not a method. It's a property which stores anonymous function.

If you want to check if value of property can be called as function you can use `is_callable`:

```
var_dump(is_callable([$obj, "test"]));
```